# changing background image when clicked a li of nav in css

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I want to change the background color of this `nav` when active/clicked, how can I achieve this? using css

```
    <div class="row container-fluid mainTabCon" style="width: 100%" style="">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin: 0 auto; ">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#"><strong>GENERALIDADES</strong></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#"><strong>DESEMPEÑO</strong></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

help is appreciated

Comment: apply css `nav-link:active, nav-link:focus { //your css code }`

Comment: Customize Your Code Accordingly.
https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/bByZdG

Comment: You mean on hover?

Comment: Do you actually mean when clicked, or do you mean *when the page is active*?

Comment: I get the impression that you're asking for  help with basic CSS. Please take a stab at it and show your attempt. Tell us what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Add this script to the end of the body or your script file:
(taken from w3 schools and adjusted to you)

```
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDiv");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var lis = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

Then just style the .active class:

```
.active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Full page with code described:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
    .active {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="row container-fluid mainTabCon" id="myDiv" style="width: 100%" style="">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin: 0 auto; ">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#"><strong>GENERALIDADES</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#"><strong>DESEMPEÑO</strong></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the container element
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    // Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
    var lis = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");

    // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After some discussion with other users, are you referring to Bootstrap's js libraries? If not, add them to the end of the body and ignore the code above to see if it works.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This code would be vastly simplified by using jQuery, the standard library for Bootstrap projects.

Comment: Active class is already there near nav-link in OP's HTML and I guess that's working correctly because he's using bootstrap. Then too, your attempt to explain is quite good. But bit difficult for a new learner to understand. (just an opinion)

Comment: @JoykalInfotech Now that I think of it you are right. Is code should work without any additional scripts. Maybe he is not referring Bootstrap JS?

Comment: Yes, this might be a reason.